# Creating a shared link for a Dropbox file using curl & C++

Tags: c++, curl, dropbox

I want to create a shared link for a dropbox file using curl & C++ on a windows 10 desktop.

I've already manage to upload the file to a dropbox folder using curl & C++.

When I try to create the link with command line it works with

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings --header "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"path\":\"path_of_the_file\"}"
```

but when I use this code to do the same in C++ it hangs at < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

Here is my code :

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    string readBuffer;
    printf("Running curl test get shared link.\n");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);              //no ssl
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; // init to NULL is important 
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: ");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"path_of_file\"}");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings");
    // Perform the request, res will get the return code
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    // Check for errors 
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

    // always cleanup 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    cout << readBuffer << endl;
    printf("\nFinished curl test.\n");

}
curl_global_cleanup();

printf("Done get shared link!\n");
```

I've tried with content-type : application/json and adding fields but I can't reproduce what I'm doing with the command line

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the code, causing undefined behaviour.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

cUrl has a C API, C does not have overloads. Thus `curl_easy_setopt` is a multi-arg function, and the third argument type depends on the second argument value. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` require long values, you pass the values as int. The size of the third argument is important exactly like this is in `*printf` functions. The proper calls must be

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

The second. 100 Continue means you have not passed the data for the POST request. The server received request and waits for further data. See
[libcurl example - http-post.c](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html).

> I can't reproduce what I'm doing with the command line

Add the `--libcurl` to the command line for getting a C code performing the same actions as in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you S.M. Here is the code that works

```
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

   curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    string readBuffer;
    printf("Running curl test get shared link.\n");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);             //no ssl
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; // init to NULL is important 
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"path\":\"path_to_the_file"}");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings");
    // Perform the request, res will get the return code
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    // Check for errors 
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

    // always cleanup 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    cout << readBuffer << endl;
    printf("\nFinished curl test.\n");

}
curl_global_cleanup();

printf("Done get shared link!\n");
```